# How to make clickable area of button be the buttons frame

Tags: macos, button, swiftui

First attempt at SwiftUI here, converting a Swift Macos app to SwiftUI.

I'm wondering if it is possible to have the entire area within a Buttons frame be clickable as a part of the button.  Seems only the highlighted area around the text is a part of the button.

[Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zv0sP.png)

Code for one of the calculator buttons:

```swift
Button("÷", action: {
    self.calculatorVM.operate("÷")
})
    .frame(width: self.calculatorVM.buttonWidth, height: self.calculatorVM.buttonHeight)
    .border(Color.blue)
    .font(.body)
```

Comment: It is possible. Would you provide code for demo?

Answer (score 0):

Got it squared away by configuring the button as follows:

```
Button(action: {
        self.calculatorVM.recieveInput(self.button)
    }) {
        Text(button.title)
            .font(.body)
            .frame(width: buttonWidth, height: 50)
            .background(button.buttonHeight)
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```